# Laravel 4 : NotFoundHttpException

Tags: exception, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm really new to Laravel, and am trying to just get a Form to work in general.

So I have a page (admin/index) that just have a form to it that has the route that maps to AdminController@test. The form submits fine but then I get a NotFoundHttpException. :(

The code for the form builder in index.blade.php is:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
Admin
@stop

@section('content')
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'test', 'method' => 'get')) }} <!-- Works with AdminController@index -->
    {{ Form::text('info') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

The route in question is:

```
    Route::get('/admin/test/' , array( 'as' => 'test' , 
                                       'uses' => 'AdminController@test'));
```

And the controller in question is:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController{


    public function index(){
        return View::make('admin.index');
    }

    public function test(){
        error_log('Yay!');
    }

}
```

Like I said, simple form on admin/index , submits, but it doesn't make it to the controller, just to the NotFoundHttpException.

Edit:
The form's HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/showknowledge/admin/test/" 
accept-charset="UTF-8">   
 <input name="info" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried pointing the form directly at the action on the controller? `{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminController@test', 'method' => 'get')) }}`

Comment: Yes, just tried that and same problem. :(

Comment: Oh hang on, what happens in the process of the Request, once the form has been submitted?  It writes `Yay` to the Log, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't even get there, the problem seems to be happening in the routing since the function throwing the error is handleRoutingException in Routing.php

Comment: what does the form's HTML look like on the page?  can you include above?

Comment: I edited and added it just now.

Comment: ah ok, can you declare your route like this?  `Route::get('admin/test/' , array( 'as' => 'test' , 'uses' => 'AdminController@test'));`

Comment: Still the same problem. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35540/discussion-between-msturdy-and-samuraisoulification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be clearer to move your Routing logic into the `AdminController` and use a [RESTful controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers):

in `routes.php` add this, and remove the two route definitions for `/admin/index` and `/admin/test`:

```
Route::controller('admin' , 'AdminController');
```

This directs all requests to `admin/` to your AdminController.  now you need to rename your functions to include the HTTP verb (GET, POST or any), and the next component of your route:

```
public function getIndex()  // for GET requests to admin/index
{ 
    //blha blah blah 
}

public function getTest()  // for GET requests to admin/test
{ 
    //blha blah blah 
}
```

Finally, update your form to use that route directly through the `action` keyword:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminController@getTest', 'method' => 'get')) }}
```

note, using `missingMethod()` to catch unhandled requests is really useful too, more info in the Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#handling-missing-methods

Hope that helps